# Using groupby and unstack

Tags: python

I have some F1 racing data as shown below. There are multiple drivers, each driving multiple stints (1-6) on a particular tyre compound (soft, medium, hard):

[image]

I'd like to unstack this into another dataframe that indicates the driver and what tyre compound they use for their stint like so:

[image: How I'd like it to look]

Here's a sample of the dataframe:

```
data = {'Driver': ['Driver A', 'Driver A', 'Driver A', 'Driver B', 'Driver B', 'Driver C'],
'Stint': [1, 1, 3, 1, 2, 3],
'Tire_Compound': ['Soft', 'Soft', 'Hard', 'Medium', 'Soft', 'Medium']}
```

The closest I've come to this result is by using:

```
F1.groupby(['Driver', 'Stint', 'Compound']).size().unstack('Stint', fill_value ='')
```

However, I don't care about the size, as a driver can only use a particular compound in a stint. Any suggestions welcome

[image: What I've tried]

Thanks!

Comment: `df.pivot(index="Driver", columns="Stint", values="Compound")` ?

Answer (score 2):

Tried to imitate your input and did this:

```
import pandas as pd

# Sample data
data = {'Driver': ['Driver A', 'Driver A', 'Driver A', 'Driver B', 'Driver B'],
        'Stint': [1, 2, 3, 1, 2],
        'Tire_Compound': ['Soft', 'Medium', 'Hard', 'Medium', 'Soft']}

f1_data = pd.DataFrame(data)

# unstack
unstacked_data = f1_data.pivot(index='Driver', columns='Stint', values='Tire_Compound')

# you may rename for clarity
unstacked_data.columns = [f'Stint_{col}' for col in unstacked_data.columns]
unstacked_data.reset_index(inplace=True)

# Fill NaN values something
unstacked_data.fillna('No Data', inplace=True)

# Display the unstacked DataFrame
print(unstacked_data)
```

Comment: Hey! Thanks for your comment. This code returns an "Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape" because a driver can have multiple rows of the same stint in the dataframe, but their tyre compound will be the same, which is why I used groupby at first. I'll edit my question using input.